# Access value of sibling control on window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I have this in my `Window.Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ValueConverters:StudyPointWorkingOn x:Key="StudyPointWorkingOn" />

    <Style x:Key="StudyPointComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedStudentItem" ElementName="oclmEditor" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StudyPointComboItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Within my `MainWindow` code I have several places where I use the above resources. Here is one example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <Label Content="Student:"/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" IsEnabled="False"
                Text="{Binding BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"
                DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                    Command="{Binding ApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="BibleReadingMain">
            <Image Source="Images/AssignmentTypeBibleReading16.png" Margin="2"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <Label Content="Study:"/>

    <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I have included it in context to show my issue. Firstly I must point out that it works as it is. The problem I now encounter is because I want to change the logic slightly.

See the `TextBox` object that preceeds the `ComboBox` by a couple of controls:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" IsEnabled="False"
        Text="{Binding BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

If possible I would like to pass the Text value `BibleReadingMainName` as the parameter in the MultiBinding object. But it is complicated because I have several places where I have this style of:

```
[Text][Button]
[Label]
[Combo]
```

So in each instance the [Text] element has a different name and the associated property would be different. Is there any way that I can still use one resource but somehow pass the `TextBox.Text` or appropriate `Property`? I know that I can use `RelativeSource` but this is for finding ancesters and this is more like a nephew ... :)

### Update

Thankyou for the answer provided so far. Please allow me to show you what I have done as I can't *yet* quite see how to implement this as you suggest with a `ViewModel`.

1. I adjusted my `Windows.Resources`

   ```
   <Style x:Key="StudyPointComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
       <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Value="True">
               <DataTrigger.Binding>
                   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                       <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                       <Binding Path="DataContext" ElementName="oclmEditor" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                       <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}"/>
                   </MultiBinding>
               </DataTrigger.Binding>
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="StudyPointComboItem">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
           <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

As you can see, I now pass in the `ComboBox` `Tag` property aswell.

2. My various ComboBox controls are now defined like this (3 of them shown):

As you can see, each `ComboBox` sets its `Tag` to the appropriate property in the `ViewModel` (that is subnsequently connected to it's own TextBox).

3. The `Converter` method now looks like this:

   namespace OCLMEditor.ValueConverters
   {
       class StudyPointWorkingOn : IMultiValueConverter
       {
           public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
           {
               int iStudyNumber = (int)values[0];
               OCLMEditorViewModel vm = (OCLMEditorViewModel)values[1];
               string strStudent = (string)values[2];

   ```
           if (vm != null && strStudent != null)
           {
               Student oStudent = vm.FindStudent(strStudent);
               if (oStudent != null && oStudent.IsWorkingOnStudyPoint(iStudyNumber))
                   return true;
           }

           return false;
       }

       public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Finally, I had to add a public wrapper method to the ViewModel:

   public Student FindStudent(string strStudent)
   {
       return _Model.FindStudent(strStudent);
   }

The above methodology works for me. But the answer provided was to use a `ViewModel` to wrap the `StudyPointItem` and the associated `Name` property. I couldn't quite see how the proposed code reflected the workflow above.

Comment: Proper ViewModel would be the way to go. Values can be passed across controls easily using ViewModel property Binding.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan The problem is using template code for several controls. I have access to the properties. Later today I will look at using the Tag property. If I bind the appropriate name property to the combo box tag then I can just pass that in. Then my code will still be generic to be able to use it in the 12 different locations.

Comment: Your StackPanel and its contents remains same but name of TextBox (and/or controls changes) ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan No. I have 12 of them and 12 text boxes. But each combo is related to each text box.

Comment: You have same StackPanel but it is appearing at 12 places with TextBoxes having diff names. Like we have `Button` control, and it appears at multiple places . Same control having its customized version appearing at various places.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Yes. When you put it like that.

Comment: You can write an attached property to find nephew which will be easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, instead of looking for the information navigating through the tree of controls, I would somehow pass the necessary information to each item you are binding. Therefore I think it is more maintainable because if the layout changes, you don't have to update the binding.

In your case, the DataContext of each item of the combobox is each element of ReadingStudyPointsList. So you could pass a reference to the actual ViewModel that has BibleReadingMainName, es ist, when you create the element you pass the "this" instance to access every property of the ViewModel:

```
this.ReadingStudyPointsList.Add(new ReadingStudyPointItemViewModel(this, other parameters))
```

So then in your ReadingStudyPointItemViewModel you could have a property that holds the parent ViewModel assigned in the ctor to access the information you need:

```
public ParentViewModel ParentVM { get; set; }
```

Finally, your binding would become:

```
<Style x:Key="StudyPointComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedStudentItem" ElementName="oclmEditor" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.ParentVM.BibleReadingMainName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a little difficulty trying to do it like you have suggested because you have hardcoded the `BibleReadingMainName` property into the generic `Style`. This property needs to be different for each `ComboBox`. I have resolved it as described at the bottom of my question by making use of the `ComboBox` `Tag` property.